# Testng Test Suite xml - Stop execution and generate report

Tags: java, automation, testng

I have a number of testng test cases listed in my Test_Suite.xml file

```
<suite name="google" verbose="3">
<parameter name="selenium.host" value="localhost"></parameter>
<parameter name="selenium.port" value="4444"></parameter>
<parameter name="selenium.browser" value="*firefox"></parameter>
<parameter name="selenium.url" value="http://www.google.com"></parameter>
<test name="name2" preserve-order="true">
<classes>
<class name="com.TestSuite.TestCase1">
<methods>
<include name="tc_TestCase1"></include>
</methods>
</class>
<class name="com.TestSuite.TestCase2">
<methods>
<include name="tc_TestCase2"></include>
</methods>
</class>
...
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Now if I run the the .xml file, it will run each test case and finally generate a report for the test cases (pass/fail)

Now , I am building a GUI interface which will allow you to run the test cases by button clicks.
I wanted to know if I added a stop command, **is there any way to stop the testng test case execution and generate the report for all the previously executed test cases?**

Currently my "Run Test Case" command

```
    // Create object of TestNG Class
    TestNG runner=new TestNG();

    // Create a list of String
    List<String> suitefiles=new ArrayList<String>();

    // Add xml file which you have to execute
    suitefiles.add("<file path>\\test_suite.xml");

    // now set xml file for execution
    runner.setTestSuites(suitefiles);

    // finally execute the runner using run method
    runner.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create and register your own `ITestListener` which will update your GUI in real time (like eclipse).

Check [the logging part of the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging) for more details.